# I'm using **Libgdx**, input events don't work when using **Multi-OS Engine**

Tags: ios, libgdx

It works fine in Android and Desktop. But when running on iOS, it doesn't respond any input event.
I'm using **gdxVersion 1.9.5**, **multi-os engine 1.2.3**
I wrote a test class extends input adapter and override touchDown and touchUp method. But it doesn't respond any of the input events which work fine in Android.

```
public class TestScreen extends ScreenAdapter implements InputProcessor {

private CardGame game;
private OrthographicCamera guiCam;

public TestScreen(CardGame game){
    this.game = game;
    guiCam = new OrthographicCamera(Consts.WORLD_WIDTH, Consts.WORLD_HEIGHT);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}

public void draw () {
    GL20 gl = Gdx.gl;
    gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    guiCam.update();
}

public void render (float delta) {
    draw();
}


@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    System.out.println("key down");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    System.out.println("key up");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    System.out.println("key typed");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    System.out.println("touch down");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    System.out.println("touch up");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    System.out.println("touch dragged");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    System.out.println("mouse moved");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    System.out.println("scrolled");
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific on you question, because it's not enough information. The touch methods should work on both Android and iOS (I've release 3 games using Multi-OS Engine). You might post your question on the [Multi-OS Engine Forum](http://discuss.multi-os-engine.org/).

Comment: I post the code of the class. none of these log printed on my console no matter how i click and drag the screen

Comment: Hmm...I can't see any `Viewport`, so that could be a resize problem. Also your code looks strange to me, because you are not using a `Stage`. But anyway, try to override the `resize` method and put in the following:
`guiCam.position.set(Consts.WORLD_WIDTH / 2, Consts.WORLD_HEIGHT / 2, 0f);`
You should also put it after the cam initialization. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this is just a test screen to demonstrate the situation I'm in. Actually in my project game screens do extend from Stage.  I setup a new project and wrote copy these codes in to the project and this problem somehow disappear..

Comment: well I add these two lines in the proguard.append.cfg and problem solved..-keep class com.badlogic.** { *; }
-keep enum com.badlogic.** { *; }